# How to match number pattern in python's responses library

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am unit testing in Python (pytest, responses library - It's for an API project...). I am creating fake responses which have to match a request string. The only difference in those responses is the number in the middle of the string:

```
    responses.add(
        GET, 
        'http://app/projects/1200979733003518/tasks?opt_pretty=false', 
        status=200,
        body=json.dumps(res_t)
    )
    responses.add(
        GET, 
        'http://app/projects/1200979733003526/tasks?opt_pretty=false', 
        status=200,
        body=json.dumps(res_t)
    )
    responses.add(
        GET, 
        'http://app/projects/1201345940827570/tasks?opt_pretty=false', 
        status=200,
        body=json.dumps(res_t)
    )
```

I want to get rid of the repetition. I tried using python's re.compile, my idea was to do something like this:

```
    responses.add(
    GET, 
    re.compile('http://app/projects/\\[0-9]+/tasks?opt_pretty=false'), 
    status=200,
    body=json.dumps(res_t)
)
```

It doesn't work. Read the manual for re, but can't come up with a working solution. How can i achieve that the response matches any number in my strings at this position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to generate random values, you can use something like this:

```
id = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=16))

responses.add(
    GET, 
    f'http://app/projects/{id}/tasks?opt_pretty=false', 
    status=200,
    body=json.dumps(res_t)
)
```

Or if you want to use know values, you can use something like [Pytest Parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) feature. That would look like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("id", ["123456789", "897654321", "654789123"])
def test_api(id):

    ...

    responses.add(
        GET, 
        f'http://app/projects/{id}/tasks?opt_pretty=false',
        status=200,
        body=json.dumps(res_t)
    )
```

With parametrize, your test will run like in a "for loop" which every run, the `id` will have a different given value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it is not what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: i have a function f in which i want to match two possible strings. So my problem is to define a variable outside of this function which would make both those strings match.

Comment: Something like `code` myvar="string_a || string_b" `code` . Unfortunately i am unable to identify the correct approach for this in python.